# why VScode sometimes don't find the reference?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

It doesn't happen all the time, but sometimes the Visual Studio Code cannot find a variable that is in other file, and I don't know why.

For example, I have a index.html

```
<script src="monitor.js"></script>
<script src="notificationManager.js"></script>
```

notificationManager.js

```
var NotificationManager = function() {
    this.attentionRequest = function() {
       console.log("Attention");
    };
}
var notificationManager = new NotificationManager();
```

in my monitor.js:

```
notificationManager.attentionRequest();//VSCode don't find this
```

[it happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMe9a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the variable/function declared in js file that is not available at the time of access. Hence, you need to change the order of JS files

Update from

```
<script src="monitor.js"></script>
<script src="notificationManager.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="notificationManager.js"></script>
<script src="monitor.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. It's so sad, I was enjoying VSCode. WebStorm solve this problem but It's not free.

Comment: But like I said, even changing the order in index.html sometimes it happens yet

Comment: @JonathanNascimento - There must be some asynchronous operation going on for that to happen. Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: no unfortunately, I don't know why it happens so I can't reproduce

Comment: @JonathanNascimento - Okay. In any case the order should be fixed as mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a refererence directive in your code pointing to the file you want to reference.

Simply put `/// <reference path="<path to file>" />` at the start of your source file.

See [Triple-Slash Directives.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)

Comment: I don't know why the first three slashes were removed in my answer. They were there because it is a XML comment, and removing them makes my answer invalid.

Comment: I couldn't find a good way in VSCode to automatically add the needed triple slash directive reference, so I created this snippet for use which is easy enough: http://www.allenconway.net/2018/09/visual-studio-code-snippet-triple-slash.html